# Firebase analytics - Difference in screen_view and session_start count

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Recently noticed some difference in `Users` count of `screen_view` and `session_start` events. Which one will be used in Active Users calculation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In short `session_start` is an application-level metric, while `screen_view` is a lower level event about views within your app. So if your app has more screens, the later will be generally higher count. A bit more precisely:

> `screen_view` when a screen transition occurs and any of
>   the following criteria are met:
>
> - No screen was previously set
> - The new screen name differs from the previous screen name
> - The new screen-class
>     name differs from the previous screen-class name
> - The new screen id differs from the previous screen id
>
> `session_start` on the other hand is when a user engages
>   the app for more than the minimum session duration after a period of
>   inactivity that exceeds the session timeout duration.

Please refer to more details in the Firebase docs:

- https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en

Comment: Thanks. 
But I am looking for the user count and NOT event count. I assume the user count is the same in both cases, irrespective of the sessions or screen views.

Answer (score 0):

We just had this question asked of us, and looking at the screen_view metrics provided some possible explanation.  Firebase released an update to how they track sessions, see here.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/12/new-changes-sessions-user-engagement.html

So in theory using the old calculation if you have users who just quickly opened the app for less than 10 seconds, it would count as a screen_view but not as a session_start.  This means that your session_start user count would be less than your screen_view user count.

Based on the update, this scenario will no longer be the case and they should start to match up moving forward.

**EDIT:**  Note that in order to use the new calculation, you'll need to install the latest Firebase SDK with you app.